# How to pass "Json string" from groovy variable to shell variable with in the groovy function

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to create shared libs for jenkins to build the app. When I am trying to pass the the json string from groovy function to shell block for build command execution. whereas json string  passing without quotes. How to retain the quotes.

```
stage('build app') {
      steps {
          script { 
                build project:"TestApp.xcodeproj",
                workspace: "TestApp.xcworkspace",
                scheme: "Develop",
                config: "Debug", 
                target: "{ "TestApp": { "info_plist": "TestApp/Info.plist", "profile_name": "Test App Debug (January 2021)", "app_id": "com.******.Debug" } }"                    
                }
            }
        }
```

```
def build(Map buildParams) {
     sh """#!/bin/bash -l
          export XCODE_PROJ="${buildParams.project}"
          export XCODE_WORKSPACE="${buildParams.workspace}"
          export XCODE_BUILD_SCHEME="${buildParams.scheme}"
          export XCODE_BUILD_CONFIGURATION="${buildParams.config}"
          export XCODE_TARGET_JSON="${buildParams.target}"

          #build App
         fastlane build app    
      """
}
```

Expecting the json string as it is in shell block with "Quotes". Whereas getting error expecting  '}' found :.  When i escape the quotes of json strings, getting, values without "quotes"

```
{ TestApp: { info_plist: TestApp/Info.plist, profile_name: Test App Debug (January 2021), app_id: com.******.Debug } }
```

which results fastlane throwing error invalid token. How to retain the quotes in shell block variable

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the quotes in json string with backslash() is worked for me.

'{ "TestApp": { "info_plist": "TestApp/Info.plist", "profile_name": "Test App Debug (January 2021)", "app_id": "com.******.Debug" } }'